# does $lookup use indexes in the foreignField key?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes, mongodb-lookup

In the example below, if the collection `inventory` has an index on the `sku` field, will it be used in this $lookup operation?

```
db.orders.insertMany( [
   { "_id" : 1, "item" : "almonds", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 },
   { "_id" : 2, "item" : "pecans", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 },
   { "_id" : 3  }
] )

db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { "_id" : 1, "sku" : "almonds", "description": "product 1", "instock" : 120 },
   { "_id" : 2, "sku" : "bread", "description": "product 2", "instock" : 80 },
   { "_id" : 3, "sku" : "cashews", "description": "product 3", "instock" : 60 },
   { "_id" : 4, "sku" : "pecans", "description": "product 4", "instock" : 70 },
   { "_id" : 5, "sku": null, "description": "Incomplete" },
   { "_id" : 6 }
] )

db.orders.aggregate( [
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "inventory",
         localField: "item",
         foreignField: "sku",
         as: "inventory_docs"
       }
  }
] )
```

EDITED:

It does not. Why not?

```
{
    "explainVersion" : "1",
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "namespace" : "6303c64faf8ef53d8ba2062f_y22_test2.orders",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    },
                    "queryHash" : "8B3D4AB8",
                    "planCacheKey" : "D542626C",
                    "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached" : false,
                    "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached" : false,
                    "maxScansToExplodeReached" : false,
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "inventory",
                "as" : "inventory_docs",
                "localField" : "item",
                "foreignField" : "sku"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: The explain (thanks for taking a look at it and for sharing it) is showing that there is a collection scan on the _source_ (`orders`) collection. It actually isn't saying anything about how the `$lookup` is operating. Can you gather the `"executionStats"` verbosity? The database should use an index, but that would help confirm

Answer (score 1):

In the case of simple lookups (e.g., when specifying a localField + foreignField), an index will be used

Things are sadly more complicated when using a $lookup + pipeline, the following limitations apply:

> 1. Multikey indexes are not used.
> 2. Indexes are not used for comparisons where the operand is an array or the
>    operand type is undefined.
> 3. Indexes are not used for comparisons with more than one field path operand.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

It is really annoying that the `explain()` call doesn't provide any information on index usage of lookup stages. The best way I've found to determine whether an index was used was to (separately) use the `$indexStats` aggregation on the collection being looked up, in the above case:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([{$indexStats: {}}])
```

Then find the index you think is being used and watch the `accesses.ops` field.

Comment: It does show index usage (though not the _plan_) when using `"executionStats"` verbosity in newer versions

Comment: Probably time for me to upgrade!